# Unable to print the IP of a request on an expressjs server behind nginx?

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

I tried the following solution:

```
app.enable('trust proxy');
...
console.log(req.ip);                        // gives ::ffff:127.0.0.1
console.log(req.ips);                       // gives []
console.log(req.header('x-forwarded-for')); // gives undefined 
console.log(req.connection.remoteAddress);  // gives ::ffff:127.0.0.1
```

Is there any other way?

Is this a symptom of a bigger problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use the X-Forwarded-For header then you need to set it with nginx first:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
```

See the docs:

- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header